# Rails 4: Poor design to have tables with unused columns depending on value of attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused on how to build a `Prescription` model.

I have an `Order` model (a.k.a purchase), and it should `have_one :prescription`. However, my prescription types vary immensely. The columns all dependent on the prescription type:

```
    Uploaded Prescription:
    file:string (will use Carrierwave)

    Manual Prescription:
    left_eye_sph:string
    left_eye_cyl:string
    left_eye_axis:string
    right_eye_sph:string
    right_eye_cyl:string
    right_eye_axis:string

    Reader Prescription:
    degrees:string
```

Would this be a good place to use Single Table Inheritance even though none of the attributes seem to overlap from type to type? I can't think of any other ways to build it.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a Prescription Model as follows:

```
class Order
  has_many :prescriptions
end

class Prescription
  belongs_to :prescribable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :order

  scope :manual_prescriptions, -> { where(prescribable_type: 'ManualPrescription') }
  # Do this for the other types
end

class ManualPrescription
  has_many :prescriptions, as: :prescribable
end

class UploadedPrescription
  has_many :prescriptions, as: :prescribable
end

class ReaderPrescription
  has_many :prescriptions, as: :prescribable
end
```

In this way you can keep adding additional prescription types as and when you might require it in the future while being easier to maintain than using STI.